# Make a function of a class only visible in certain places in php

Tags: php, api, security

I’m currently building a CMS and I have been trying to figure this out forever now.
So, I’m building this CMS so that people may make Themes, Widgets. etc for it.

My problem is, that there is functionality within the CMS core that i do not want developers to have access to, and whole classes that I don’t want them to be able to use.

An example of a function I do not want developers to have access to would be the createNewUser function.

A class i don’t want developers to have access to is the database class.

I have thought about using db_backtrace at the top of every function I want to keep "private to the CMS core", but this seems very unwise.

Any solution that involves passing an extra parameter to the function is undesirable as there is already, and will be more, function I need to keep private to the core, and this type of solution would most likely be easy to spoof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

-edit-

I’m not sure I’m making myself clear.
I will indeed be hosting it myself, although I would like to allow developers to host it locally them self allowing for local development.
I will have no problems knowing what function/classes the developers should have access to, what i’m having problems figuring out is how to implement it; Allowing one part of the system(The Core) to call a function, but not allowing a different part(The Theme).
Say I have a class

```
class DataBase {
    public static function doSomething() {
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

How do I make doSomething visible for the core, but not for files included, that I consider not to be the a part of the core.

Comment: All of this depends on the level of access that these developers will have.

Comment: It depends on what you want them to be able to do. You should first take a look at normal users and note down exactly what their needs are, then take a look at functionality only needed by members. Having it listed up makes it easy to see straight away what is needed by whom. If everything works then you're not missing anything. We can't tel you exactly what members should be allowed to and not since it depends on each system.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to find the methods of compiled and 'hidden' modules. If you want to prevent access, host it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debug_backtrace()` function to get caller information. Something like:

```
class DataBase {
  public static function doSomething() {
      $allowed = false;
      foreach(debug_backtrace() as $trace) {
         switch($trace['class']) {
          case 'Core':
          case 'AnotherAllowedClass':
          $allowed = true;
          break 2;
        }
      }
      if(!$allowed)
       throw new Exception('denied');
      /* do stuff */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As an additional note, you can use this as a "gateway" function, and with reasonable use of the 'private' keyword, can make a walled garden around your internal code.

Comment: I appreachiate your answer, although I did specify in my question that I do not wan’t to use debug_backtrace, as i suspect that i might run into performance issues if debug_backtrace is called like this in a lot of functions.

Comment: That would be awesome. Any idea how likely it is that this will be included in PHP 5.6/7/8? Or how likely it is that it will be a part of the php core within a year?

Comment: It has an open state, os I can only guess. I think it would be something like a "namespace" visibility keyword.